# If Multiple Google Maps on Same page, clicking any marker highlights bottom-most map marker

Tags: javascript, ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3

First off, I'm not having an issue getting the maps to display correctly, and the markers are where they need to be on the map.  My issue is when I have multiple maps shown for a state, if you click the marker to show the `infowindow` on any map, the `contentString` pops up for the bottom-most map.

Here is the code displaying the map(s) on the page:

```
<% @showrooms_nearby.each do |showroom| %>
      <% address_url = "" %>
      <div class="row showroom-results">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div id="<%= showroom.id %>" style="height:400px; width:100%; clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title"><%= showroom.name %></h4>
              <div class="showroom-info showroom-address">
                <% if showroom.design_center %>
                  <% address_url = address_url + " #{showroom.design_center}" %>
                  <%= showroom.design_center %> <br>
                <% end %>
                <% if showroom.address1 %>
                  <% address_url = address_url + " #{showroom.address1}" %>
                  <%= showroom.address1 %> <br>
                <% end %>
                <% if showroom.address2 %>
                  <% address_url = address_url + " #{showroom.address2}" %>
                  <%= showroom.address2 %> <br>
                <% end %>
                <% if showroom.address3 %>
                  <% address_url = address_url + " #{showroom.address3}" %>
                  <%= showroom.address3 %> <br>
                <% end %>
                <% if showroom.city %>
                  <% address_url = address_url + " #{showroom.city}" %>
                  <%= showroom.city %>,&nbsp;
                <% end %>
                <% if showroom.state %>
                  <% address_url = address_url + " #{showroom.state}" %>
                  <%= showroom.state %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <% end %>
                <% if showroom.zip %>
                  <% address_url = address_url + " #{showroom.zip}" %>
                  <%= showroom.zip %> <br>
                <% end %>
                <% if showroom.country != 'US' %>
                  <% address_url = address_url + " #{showroom.country}" %>
                  <% showroom.country %> <br>
                <% end %>
              </div>
              <div class="showroom-info showroom-contact">
                <% if showroom.phone %>
                  Phone: <%= showroom.phone %> <br>
                <% end %>
                <% if showroom.fax %>
                  Fax: <%= showroom.fax %> <br>
                <% end %>
                <% if showroom.email %>
                  <%= mail_to showroom.email %> <br>
                <% end %>
                <% if showroom.website %>
                  <%= link_to showroom.website %> <br>
                <% end %>
              </div>
              <div class="showroom-info showroom-brands">
                <% if showroom.brands %>
                  Brands:<br>
                  <% brand_sort(showroom.brands).each_with_index do |brand, index| %>
                    <% if index == showroom.brands.size - 1 %>
                      <%= brand_pretty(brand) %>&nbsp;
                    <% else %>
                      <%= brand_pretty(brand) %>,
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
              <div class="showroom-info showroom-links">
                <a href="https://maps.google.com?daddr=<%= address_url.parameterize.gsub('-', '+') %>" target="_blank">Get Directions</a>
              </div>
              <script>$(window).load(function() {initMap('<%= showroom.id %>', <%= showroom.latitude %>, <%= showroom.longitude %>);});</script>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="showroom-divider">
    <% end %>
```

Here is the maps.js.erb:

```
var map;
function initMap(id, lat, lng) {
  myLatLng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};

  contentString = "Brand Showroom";

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

showroom.js:

```
function displayShowrooms(country, state, stateName) {

  var jShowroomHeader = $("span.showroom-location");
  var jShowroomWrapper = $("div.showroom-wrapper");

  if (jShowroomWrapper.length) {
    if (country == 'US') {
      var strURI_Showrooms = ("/showrooms/" + country + "/" + state);
    } else {
      var strURI_Showrooms = ("/showrooms/" + country);
    }


    $.ajax(strURI_Showrooms, {
      method : "GET",
      async  : true ,
      cache  : false,
      timeout: 5000 ,
      headers: { "X-CSRF-Token": $("meta[name=csrf-token]").prop("content") }
    }) // [ajax, get list of showrooms matching our selection]

      .done(function (objData) {
        jShowroomHeader.empty().append("Showrooms in " + stateName);
        jShowroomWrapper.empty();

        if (objData.length) {
          $.each(objData, function(index, showroom) {
            jShowroomWrapper.append(" \
              <div class='row' id='showroom-result-" + showroom.id + "'> \
                <div class='col-md-8'> \
                  <div id='"+ showroom.id +"' style='height:400px; width:100%; clear:both;'></div> \
                </div> \
                <div class='col-md-4'> \
                  <div class='card'> \
                    <div class='card-block'> \
                      <h4 class='card-title'>" + showroom.name +"</h4> \
                      <a class='showroomAddressLink' target='_blank'>  \
                      <div class='showroom-info showroom-address'> \
                      </div> \
                      </a> \
                      <div class='showroom-info showroom-contact'> \
                      </div> \
                      <div class='showroom-info showroom-brands'> \
                        Brands:<br> \
                      </div> \
                      <div class='showroom-info showroom-links'> \
                      </div> \
                    </div> \
                  </div> \
                </div> \
              </div> \
              <hr class='showroom-divider'> \
              ");
            var jShowroomResult = jShowroomWrapper.find('#showroom-result-'+showroom.id);
            var address_url = showroom.name;
            if (showroom.design_center != null) {
              jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-address').append(showroom.design_center + "<br>");
              address_url += " " + showroom.design_center;
            }
            if (showroom.address1 != null) {
              jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-address').append(showroom.address1 + "<br>");
              address_url += " " + showroom.address1;
            }
            if (showroom.address2 != null) {
              jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-address').append(showroom.address2 + "<br>");
              address_url += " " + showroom.address2;
            }
            if (showroom.address3 != null) {
              jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-address').append(showroom.address3 + "<br>");
              address_url += " " + showroom.address3;
            }
            if (showroom.city != null) {
              jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-address').append(showroom.city + ",&nbsp;");
              address_url += " " + showroom.city;
            }
            if (showroom.state != null) {
              jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-address').append(showroom.state + "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
              address_url += " " + showroom.state;
            }
            if (showroom.zip != null) {
              jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-address').append(showroom.zip + "<br>");
              address_url += " " + showroom.zip;
            }
            if (showroom.country != null && showroom.country != 'US') {
              jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-address').append(showroom.country + "<br>");
              address_url += " " + showroom.country;
            }
            if (showroom.phone != null) {
              jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-contact').append("Phone: " + "<a href='tel:'" + showroom.phone + ">" + showroom.phone + "</a>" + "<br>");
            }
            if (showroom.fax != null) {
              jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-contact').append("Fax: " + showroom.fax + "<br>");
            }
            if (showroom.email != null) {
              jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-contact').append("<a href='mailto:" + showroom.email + "'>" + showroom.email + "<br>");
            }
            if (showroom.website != null) {
              jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-contact').append("<a href='" + showroom.website + "' target='_blank'>" + showroom.website + "<br>");
            }
            if (showroom.brands != null) {
              $.each(showroom.brands, function (i, brand) {
                if (i == (showroom.brands.length - 1)) {
                  jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-brands').append(brand);
                } else {
                  jShowroomResult.find('.showroom-brands').append(brand + ",&nbsp;")
                }
              });
            }

            jShowroomResult.find('.showroomAddressLink').attr("href", "https://maps.google.com/?q="+address_url.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g,'+').replace(/(^-|-$)/g,''))

            initMap(showroom.id, showroom.latitude, showroom.longitude);
          }); // for [every showroom]
        } // if [we have showrooms]
        else {
          jShowroomWrapper.append("<div class='row showroom-results'><div class='col-md-12 center'>No showrooms are located in " + stateName + ". Please search another location or call (555) 555-5555 for assistance.</div>")
        }
      })
  } 
}
```

showroom_controller.rb:

```
class ShowroomsController < ApplicationController
  def landing
    lat = location.latitude
    lon = location.longitude
    @distance = 50
    @user_location = [lat, lon]
    @showrooms = Showroom.all.where('? = ANY (brands)', brand(request)).order('id ASC')
    @showrooms_nearby = @showrooms.near(@user_location, @distance)
  end

  def search
    @showrooms = if params[:state]
                   Showroom.where(country: params[:country].upcase, state: params[:state].upcase)
                 else
                   Showroom.where(country: params[:country].upcase)
                 end

    @showrooms.each do |showroom|
      showroom.brands = brand_sort(showroom.brands)
      showroom.brands.collect! { |brand|
        (brand == 'brand1') ? 'Brand1' :
        (brand == 'brand2') ? 'Brand2' :
        (brand == 'brand3') ? 'Brand3' :
        (brand == 'brand4') ? 'Brand4' :
        (brand == 'brand5') ? 'Brand5' :
        (brand == 'brand6') ? 'Brand6' : brand
      }

    end

    render json: @showrooms
  end
end
```

Thank you for any and all help guys!

Comment: Please show the Javascript code that calls initMap() for each of the showrooms, as well as the Ruby code that initializes the Javascript array of showrooms.  Whatever code is necessary to bind together the view and the dynamic behavior is needed.

Comment: Michael, I have added the showroom.js and showroom_controller.rb.  Thank you for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to have been simple: map is a global variable, so will refer to the last map defined when the click event opens the info window.  If you make map local to the initMap function, it looks like it should work.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to add `myLatLong`,`map`,`infowindow`, and `marker` as local variables.  Now it works like it should.